# How can i create a button that changes background and font text?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, fonts

Hello everyone i am completely new to Android programming and one of the things i would like to learn is how to trigger events based on button presses. so far i have only managed to create a button but i don't know how to create the events and more importantly what files do i have to modify?

activity_main.xml:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:text="@string/font_color"
        android:onClick="toggleChange"/>
```

i am mostly familiar with the files activity_main.xml and mainActivity.java and have made a function  in main activity.java:

```
public void toggleChange(){
        //not sure what goes here
    }
```

i am not sure what to place inside the function and i also not entirely sure that java alone is whats needed. Do i need to change some other XML file i don't know about? thanks for any help.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              // Perform action on click
              // Use attributes of View or cast to Button
              // to change background / text
              //v.setText ("Hello Blu");
         }
         });
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You should watch this Android series on youtube, you can learn the very basic on android development from there:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxPh1tgiK2g&list=PL4695D1A275CDEE4A

Comment: I already have Eclipse installed Paulo

Comment: I mean the series not the first video.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the more common way to do this is

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              // Perform action on click
              // Use attributes of View or cast to Button
              // to change background / text
              v.setText ("Hello Blu");
         }
         });
```

Comment: Usually this is put in the onCreate method.  Maybe safest for now.

Comment: i am getting some errors: Button cannot be resolved to a type , button_id cannot be resolved or is not a field, the method setText(string) is undefined for the type view

Comment: try importing it then

Comment: after importing android.view.view two errors went away and i am left with: button_id cannot be resolved or is not a field, and the method setText(string) is undefined for the type view

Comment: Yes, you have not given the button an ID in the xml have you.  I suggest you go right back to basics, maybe watch the youtube link that Paulo sent you.

Comment: fixing the id still does nothing

Comment: The above code should be in the `onCreate` not the `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Answer (score 0):

implement a TextView in your xml and set it up in your java. 
XML :

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

setup it on your java :

```
 private TextView mText;

        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button mButton 

= (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id. button_id);

            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mText.setText("whatever you like"); 

                }
            });
```